# Adding property in php datatable for google chart custom html tooltips

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, google-visualization

I am trying to create custom html tooltips in my google chart by adding them into the datatable, right now my datatable is being created in PHP like this:

```
  $datatable = array('cols' => array(
 array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'domain', 'label' => 'Month'),
 array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip'), 
 array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'domain', 'label' => 'Omzet'), 
 array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'Omzet '.$jaar), 
 array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'Omzet '.($jaar-1)), 
 array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'domain', 'label' => 'Aantal'), 
 array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'Aantal '.$jaar), 
 array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'Aantal '.($jaar-1))
));
```

and filled like this:

```
$datatable['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
 array('v' => $monthname),
 array('v' => '<h1>custom</h1> tooltip '.$monthname),
 array('v' => 'Omzet '.$monthname),
 array('v' => $row['totaal']),
 array('v' => $omzet),
 array('v' => 'Aantal'),
 array('v' => $row['aantal']),
 array('v' => $aantal)
));
```

however for the datatable you can specify in Javascript for the google chart, you have to add something like

```
dataTable.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
```

otherwise the tooltip would come out as plain text instead of html markup
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#customizing-html-content

which means I will have to somehow add the **'p' : { 'html' : true }** property to my datatable

I have tried by editing it to

```
array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip', 'p' => '{ html : true}'),
```

or even to

```
array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip', 'html' => true),
```

but none of these seem to work and I can't find a way to do it on google either.

I hope i've given enough information to help come up with an answer, if there's anything more you need please let me know.

This is my first time posting a question here so please be nice (:

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with PHP, but could you not try to instead of using all these 'array' try to save your input as a string?

Comment: @HenrikAronsson I'm not sure what you mean by that. This was the best way i've found to create a json datatable using php arrays

Comment: Hmm, as said, I'm not very familiar with PHP, but with some more studying of it, I believe you should keep trying with your 
`array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip', 'p' => '{ html : true}'),`. 
But as `array('type' => 'string')` would be Json `'type': 'string'` I would change your line to 
`array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip', 'p' => array('html' => true)),` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with `array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip', 'p' => '{ html : true}'),`but you need to have an additional array for the `'html': true` part.

It should look like `array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip', 'p' => array('html' => true));`

I tried it out here: [Link to test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/497caa96ae7ce2fc82af8bb0449b50a7c9c52954)

Answer (score 0):

> dataTable.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});

That is in json format. So if I understand you right you just need to convert your array into json array. In PHP you can do that via [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

Comment: Yes I am converting it to json via json_encode in the javascript to create the datatable however i cannot specify a property of the column to be the above mentioned html:true part. at least I don't know how but I guess there should be a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Alright i've managed to fix it, thing is I had to add it as an extra array element like so:

```
array('type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip', 'p' => array('html' => true)),
```

this created JSON in the format that the Google chart acccepted to turn the tooltip into HTML formatted text.