# When using JSON data, how to make the tooltip html in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I am currently trying to build Google charts and use an HTML tooltip.

The question has been already asked and I have seen the answers, see:

[Google Charts - full html in tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118920/google-charts-full-html-in-tooltips)

[Tooltip in Google Chart while populating chart using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174562/tooltip-in-google-chart-while-populating-chart-using-json)

[Adding property in php datatable for google chart custom html tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709304/adding-property-in-php-datatable-for-google-chart-custom-html-tooltips)

Unfortunately, my case is a litthe different as I am using JSON data.

So, the code I am using is:

```
{
  "cols": [
            {"id":"","label":"Graph","pattern":"","type":"number"},
            {"id":"","pattern":"","type":"number"},
            {"id":"","type":"string","role":"tooltip","p":{"html":true}}  
        ],
  "rows": [
            <?php
                // DO THE PHP LOGIC
                // My line is somethjing like  {"c":[{"v":4150,"f":null},{"v":20,"f":null},{"v":"AF545PM/1500<br/>123","f":null}]}, 
            ?>
        ]
}
```

And unfortunately, despite displaying html in tooltip, I still get a badly displayed tooltip:

[image]

Any idea what I could do to fix that?

EDIT:

Regarding first comment, I added in my graph:

```
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
  var options = {
      tooltip: {isHtml: true},
      legend: 'none'
    };
  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
```

This indeed made the legend disappear, so I am sure the option are taken in account, but the 
 is still displayed in tooltip

Comment: added this to your options? --> `tooltip: {isHtml: true}`

Comment: Hello, I just edited my answer to add the code, and with the option, the legend disappeared, but the <br/> is still displayed in tooltip

Comment: OK, you van add it as answer, so I can accept it:  I removed the html:true from json, but both are mandatory. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following must be in place for html tooltips to display properly

the tooltip column should include an html property (as in the post)
`{"id":"","type":"string","role":"tooltip","p":{"html":true}}`

the config options should include

```
  tooltip: {
    isHtml: true
  }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var jsonData = {
      "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Graph","pattern":"","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","pattern":"","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","type":"string","role":"tooltip","p":{"html":true}}
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v": 1}, {"v": 1}, {"v": "<div class='ggl-tooltip'><div>test 1</div><div>test 1</div></div>"}]},
        {"c":[{"v": 2}, {"v": 2}, {"v": "<div class='ggl-tooltip'><div>test 2</div><div>test 2</div></div>"}]}
      ]
    };

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var options = {
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```css
.ggl-tooltip {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}
.ggl-tooltip div {
  padding-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```